# Can a Mod disassociate my old questions?

Tags: support, status-completed, moderators

I have been on programmers.SE for about four months now, and I love it. Currently, I can't ask any questions, however; due to some bad questions that I asked. They have been since deleted and removed from the deleted recent questions page. I am wondering if a Mod can disassociate them from my account? This was done on StackOverflow for me. I would love to have the chance to prove myself again. Thanks.

Comment: In the spirit of helping you improve the quality of your Q&A, here are some suggestions.  1) Don't put your age in your posts.  We don't really care how old you are and it's irrelevant to the question.  Feel free to put your age in your profile if you would like.  2) Look over the main site about and help pages.  Yes, you've probably already done so once but do it again.  Get a better understanding of what's on-topic here and what forum-esque behaviors are discouraged (like adding "Thanks!" to posts) ...

Comment: … 3) Try to avoid answering or even commenting on subjects you don't have significant experience on.  Many of your down-voted answers are … poor. The conclusions you draw are evidence that you're lacking experience in those subjects.  4) Consider using [chat] for some of the more opinion based questions that you have had.  At a minimum, the chat regulars will help you identify what you need to research in order to form a solid question.

Comment: Finally, stop leaving "+1 blah blah blah" type comments.  It's forum-esque behavior that isn't really welcome on the site.  Yes, it's tolerated, but it creates more work for others to clean up.  After looking over your comment history, the majority of them appear to be stuff that the site doesn't need.  If you agree with an answer then just up vote it.  If you disagree, then down vote.  But please don't leave worthless comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked a *purely* programming question way back when which was:

- No longer visible *for* you to edit
- Unsalvageable - there's no way you could have improved that post to make it on-topic and had it restored, even if you could have found it easily to edit.

Since you've obviously got a grasp of *why* we have the automatic blocks and what we hope they will accomplish, I removed that lead weight from around your ankle and you can ask questions again.

Take care, though - I wouldn't say you're on the verge of being blocked again, but you need some good questions under your belt to get completely out of the woods.

Answer (score 5):

This is only something the community team can do.

I've passed your request along, but it's up to them whether they do this or not.